# Validate data Java class

Tags: java

Main question:
Each flight has a number (this must start with letters EI and be followed by 3 digits), a day of the week the flight travels, a destination and the number of seats booked. Each flight will also have the standard responsibilities and the ability to calculate and return the number of free seats on a flight (assume each flight has a maximum of 10). You should use your imaginations to create one other flight responsibility that you think would be useful (this could also involve the creation of one or more new data items to support the responsibility).

This is what i have done so far:

```
public class Flight{


    private String flightNo;
    private date day;
    private String 
    private int numberOfBookedSeats;
    private int freeSeats=0;
    private int passengerMeals;
    private int mealsNeeded=0;

    public Flight(){

    }

    public Flight(String flightNo, date day,String destination,int numberOfBookedSeats,int passengerMeals ){
        this.flightNo= flightNo;
        this.day = day;
        this.destination= destination;
        this.numeberOfSeats= numberOfSeats;
        this.passengerMeals= passengerMeals;

    }

    public void setFlightNo(filghtNo f){
        flightNo= f;
    }

    public String getFlightNo() {
        return flightNo;
    }

    public void setDay(Day d) {
        day= d;
    }

    public int getDay(){
        return day;
    }

    public void setDestination(destination ds) {
        destination = ds;
    }

    public int getDestination(){
        return destination;
    }

    public void setNumeberOfSeats(numberOfSeats s){
        numberOfSeats= s;
    }

    public int getNumeberOfSeats(){
        return numeberOfSeats;
    }

    public void setPassengerMeals( passengerMeals pm){
        passengerMeals= pm;
    }

    public int getPassengerMeals(){
        return passengerMeals;
    }

    public int calculateFreeSeats(){
        int maxSeatsNumbers = 10;
        freeSeats = maxSeatsNumbers - numberOfBookedSeats;
        return freeSeats;
    }

    public int calculateMealsNeeded(){
        int staffMeals=5;
        passengerMeals= numberOfBookedSeats;
        mealsNeeded= staffMeals + passengerMeals;
        return mealsNeeded;
    }
}
```

Comment: So what else do you want your code to do? StackOverflow works much better if you ask a specific question.

Comment: You want to validate "flightNo"? Thats the question?

Comment: I dont know how to create the number in the format of EI and then followed  by 3 digits. I want to know how to code it in the class flight

Answer (score 1):

An`int` is not the correct class to store the flight number as, as it does not allow for the prefix characters or for the width to be specified. You could store it as a `String`, which would allow the prefix, and then do some validation and possibly padding to the numeric part, but what I would do is create a new type to represent the flight number.

This encapsulates the logic used to generate the flight number from the prefix `String` & `int`, making it more maintainable as the validation logic is just in one place, and it makes the code more understandable as your `Flight` class no longer has to contain logic to do with generating `String` flight numbers. It's a lot more clear in use, as well, because if you have a `private final FlightNumber flightNumber` member, you can use it in a `String` with something like `"The flight number is " + flightNumber;`.

See the following for what this type could look like:

*Note this particular implementation uses [Guava's `Strings` class](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Strings.html) - if you're not using this already it's probably not worth importing it just for this, so implement an equivalent yourself using `String.format("%03d", ...)` or similar, but if you've got Guava I think it looks cleaner.*

```
import com.google.common.base.Strings;

public class FlightNumber {
    private final String prefix;
    private final int flightId;

    public FlightNumber(String prefix, int flightId) {
        if (flightId < 0 || flightId > 999) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Flight ID [" + flightId + "]");
        }
        this.prefix = prefix;
        this.flightId = flightId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return prefix + Strings.padStart(String.valueOf(flightId), 3, '0');
    }
}
```

If you wanted to extend this in the future, and your code suited this kind of design, you could then do something like the following:

```
public class AerLingusFlightNumber extends FlightNumber {

    public AerLingusFlightNumber(int flightId) {
        super("EI", flightId);
    }
}
```

And:

```
public class BritishAirwaysFlightNumber extends FlightNumber {

    public BritishAirwaysFlightNumber(int flightId) {
        super("BA", flightId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it be worth including a range check on flightId in the constructor? Your current code would accept 1000 which would not meet the requirement.

Comment: Definitely, sorry - missed that!

Answer (score 0):

If you want your fight number to be alpha numeric then `int` is not the correct data type, you should use `String` and for validating that you could use the `String` method [matches](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) in conjunction with a [regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).

Here is something you could start with:

```
class AirLine {
    List<Flight> flights = new ArrayList<>();
    public void addFlight(String flightNumber) {
        flights.add(new Flight(flightNumber));
    }
    public List<Flight> getFlights() {
        return flights;
    }
}

class Flight {
    String flightNumber;
    public Flight(String flightNumber) {
        setFlightNumber(flightNumber);
    }
    public String getFlightNumber() {
        return flightNumber;
    }
    public void setFlightNumber(String flightNumber) {
        if(flightNumber == null || ! flightNumber.matches("EI\\d{3}")) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid flight number: " 
                    + flightNumber);
        }
        this.flightNumber = flightNumber;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only create one `public Constructor` due to a Flight must have a `FlightNumber` (must be a `String`).
Also I would check at the body of the constructor the following:

```
if (!flightNumber.matchs("^EI\d{3}$")) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Flight number format.");
}
flightNo = flightNumber;
```

Comment: IllegalArgumentException might be a better choice than a raw exception. Alternatively defining a specific exception might make it clearer what has gone wrong at runtime.

Comment: @RichardMiskin, Thank you, edited my answer. (Have not written nothing at `Java` for a long time.)